# Which was is best to insert a row into a database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework

For a long time I've been doing the following:

```
using(var db = new MainContext())
{
    // Create license issue record
    var n = new tblStoreLicenseIssue
    {
        Comment = comment,
        EmailAddress = email,
        Hash = mangled2,
        LicensedTo = name,
        Timestamp = unixTime,
        ValidClaimID = validClaimID
    };

    db.tblStoreLicenseIssues.InsertOnSubmit(n);
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

But I was wondering if this method offers any advantages:

```
var n = new tblStoreLicenseIssue
{
    Comment = comment,
    EmailAddress = email,
    Hash = mangled2,
    LicensedTo = name,
    Timestamp = unixTime,
    ValidClaimID = validClaimID
};

using(var db = new MainContext())
{
    db.tblStoreLicenseIssues.InsertOnSubmit(n);
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Which method is considered best practise, and why?

Comment: i have used both styles, and there is no difference you can adopt any of them

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with the latter - as creating the object is not using the DB context, it doesn't have to be in the `using` construct.

Answer (score 1):

The only advantage the second method offers is that you would avoid constructing and disposing an instance of `MainContext` in cases when construction of your `tblStoreLicenseIssue` fails. Other than that, the two snippets are identical.